# Accessing control on page with master page from user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, web

When accessing a control on a parent page from a user control that wasn't made with a master page, all I had to do was:

```
Page sample = this.Page;
```

And I got access the parent page and the controls on it.  But when that page was made with a master page, that same code doesn't work and I get a null exception for that control.

What needs to change here?

Comment: did you try this.Master or this.Page.Master

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your maste code behind

```
    public partial class SiteMaster : MasterPage
    {
        public string PropertyInMaster { get; set; }

        protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PropertyInMaster = "test";
...
```

In your usercontrol:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var mst = this.Page.Master as SiteMaster;

    Response.Write(mst.PropertyInMaster);
```

...

You would also be able to do a findcontrol on your masters contentplaceholders, and controls within these; mst.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").FindControl("MyTextBox")...